# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, list, indices, equivalent

array = some kind of list with 3 columns and unlimited amount of rows with data inside of it.

```
Volume = array[0][2] 
counter = 0
for i in array: 
    if Volume == array[i][2]: #<------ why is this line a problem? 
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an IndexError (or TypeError, or just wrong results) from "ar\[i\]" inside "for i in ar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/why-do-i-get-an-indexerror-or-typeerror-or-just-wrong-results-from-ari-in)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a classic mistake. `i` in your case is already an element from `array` (i.e. another list), *not* an index of `array` (*not* an `int`), so

```
if Volume == i[2]:
    counter += 1
```

You can check the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Also, try doing this:

```
for i in array:
    print (i)
```

And see what you get!

Also I would advise to stick to naming conventions: variables are normally lower-case (`volume`, not `Volume`). In this case `i` is misleading. `row` or `elem` would be much more suitable.

Answer (score 8):

Also, as this may happen frequently, note that you cannot access slices of lists (but you can for an array):

```
import numpy as np
integerarray = np.array([33,11,22], dtype=int)
integerlist = [33,11,22]
indexArray = [1,2,0]  # or equivalently, an array, e.g. np.argsort(integerlist)
print(integerarray[indexArray]) ## works fine
print(integerlist[indexArray])  ## triggers: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I hope this helps.
It even happened to me that I had to convert to a float array, otherwise the object would remain of the wrong type.

Comment: fplandes, I have the same problem, for a moment my code was working, I have made some alterations in other functions, and now it throws the TypeError.
`lamb_func = lambda x,f,v: [x['data']['q']['57']['dt'], x['data']['q']['57']['meta'][f][v]['s']]`

i pass an `x` (dictionary), `f` (string) and `v` (string) arguments. How can one solve it, without amending the `lamb_func` to return results?