# List indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to loop through all items of a given class on a page:

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass"):
        elementContents=str(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")[i].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement
```

The reason for the str is because I can to be able to output the HTML contents of the elements.

Comment: Going to go out on a hunch and guess `find_elements_by_class_name` returns a sequence of `WebElement`.

Comment: `i` is already an index element of `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")`. Just use `str(i.get_attribute('innerHTML'))`. You're using `i` like it's the actual index, not the element itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329668/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-list)

Comment: Thanks, Sterling, that works beautifully. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")` returns a list of `WebElements`.  So.. in your for-loop, each iteration produces a `WebElement`, not an integer index... you don't need to use indexes at all.

Also, in the block that gets executed, you don't need to call `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("myClass")` a 2nd time.

You want to do something like:

```
for element in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('myClass'):
    element_contents = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```