# Why do I get an IndexError (or TypeError, or just wrong results) from "ar[i]" inside "for i in ar"?

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror, index-error

I'm trying to sum the values of a list using a `for` loop. This is my code:

```
def sumAnArray(ar):
    theSum = 0
    for i in ar:
        theSum = theSum + ar[i]
    return theSum
```

I get the following error:

```
line 13, theSum = theSum + ar[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I found that what I'm trying to do is apparently as simple as `sum(ar)`. But I want to understand: Why do I get this `IndexError`, and how should I write the `for` loop instead? How does the loop actually work?

---

<sub>For a **technical overview** of how Python implements `for` loops and the iterator protocol, see e.g. [How does a Python for loop with iterable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189).</sub>

Comment: `i` is the value of the item you're looping over in the array... so if you had 3 items `[10, 11, 12]` you're trying on the first iteration of accessing `ar[10]` which won't work... You could just use the builtin `sum`, eg: `sum(ar)` ?

Comment: @JonClements you will notice that I mentioned sum(ar) in my original question as an easier way to do it. I am asking how to properly iterate over array elements.

Comment: (sorry - somehow glanced over that bit) you can just change your loop to be `theSum += ar`...

Comment: If you want to use the INDEX of each element, rather than the value of each element in a list, you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: This is not 3.x-specific.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When looping over a list, the `for` variable (in this example `i`) represents the *current element of the list*.

For example, given `ar = [1, 5, 10]`, `i` will have the successive values `1`, `5` and `10` each time through the loop. Since the length of the list is 3, the [maximum permitted index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643) is 2. Thus, the second time through the loop, when `i == 5`, an `IndexError` is raised.

The code should be like this instead:

```
for i in ar:
    theSum = theSum + i
```

To be able to index into the list, use a `range` instead of iterating over the list directly:

```
for i in range(len(ar)):
    theSum = theSum + ar[i]
```

This way, `i` [naturally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533) takes on all the valid index values for `ar`.

Answer (score 7):

The for loop iterates over the *elements* of the array, *not its indices*.

Consider for example a list `ar = [2, 4, 6]`: when a loop like `for i in ar:` runs, the successive values of `i` will be `2`, `4` and `6`. The first time through the loop, `ar[i]` would work (as the last position of the list is 2, `a[2]` equals 6), but the next iteration would fail (since `a[4]` is invalid).

Try using `for index, value in enumerate(ar):`, to get [indices along with the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/); then `theSum = theSum + ar[index]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over a list or array with code like

```
ar = [10, 11, 12]
for i in ar:
    print(i)
```

will actually put the *values of* the list sequentially in `i` - so this is the resulting output:

```
10
11
12
```

However, in the original code, `i` is mistakenly treated as an index into the list. In the first iteration for this example, `ar[i]` would mean `ar[10]` - which is, of course, an out-of-range index, causing an `IndexError`.