# Check any value in a list exist in a sentence

Tags: python, list

I am trying to check whether any value in a list exist in a sentence as below:

```
rich = ["Businessman","Robber","Politician"]
poor = ["Programmer","Engineer","Doctor"]

whoAmI = "I am an Engineer"

if rich.*MISSING_HERE* in whoAmI:
    print "You are RICH"
else :
    print "You are POOR"
```

If you look at the line with the if statement, I am checking whether any element fron `rich` is available in `whoAmI`. How do I check this?

Comment: Just iterate the array `rich`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over arrays in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3)

Comment: What does `rich.*MISSING_HERE*` mean?

Comment: It means that I am missing something there to check whether `whoAmI` contains any of the elements in `rich`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any()` method -

```
if any(r in whoAmI for r in rich):
    print "You are RICH"
else :
    print "You are POOR"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [for else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) loop

```
rich = ["Businessman","Robber","Politician"]
poor = ["Programmer","Engineer","Doctor"]
whoAmI = "I am an Engineer"

for r in rich:
    if r in whoAmI:
        print "You are RICH"
        break
else:
    print "You are POOR"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `re` or regex module of Python Library to search for the word in the string. We will be using simple for loop ( Note: Time complexity : O(n))

```
import re

rich = ["Businessman","Robber","Politician"]
poor = ["Programmer","Engineer","Doctor"]

whoAmI = "I am an Businessman"

for word in rich:
    if re.search(i, whoAmI):
        print("Rich")
        quit()

print("Poor")
```

We are using Python inbuilt function `quit()` so as to prevent same outputs from displaying multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simplified answer

```
[any( j in rich for j in whoAmI.split())]
```

If it satisfies the condition, it will answer True(i.e., 'rich') else it will notify false.

Answer (score 0):

With a list of comprehension:

```
if len([x for x in rich if x in whoAmI]):
    print ("You are RICH")
else :
    print ("You are POOR")
```

> You are POOR