# Plotting dataframe data in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I've the following code for plotting two dataframe data in a single figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))


plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, squeeze=False)

df1.plot(ax=axes[0], style='o-')
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

df2.plot(ax=axes[0], style='--')
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')
```

However, I get the following error

```
fig = self.ax.get_figure()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_figure.html) is a method of `Axis`, however, `self.ax` is `ndarray` according to the error. Due to the name of `ax`, it's reasonable to assume that it's an array of `Axis` objects, so you will need to call `get_figure` of the array items, instead of the actual array.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure how this has to be implemented

Comment: @Natasha you need to iterate your array, see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3

Comment: But `pprint(len(axes))` = 1.

Comment: @Natasha that means that you have an array of a single element. You still have an array, but in this specific case you can choose to reference the first element of the array instead of iterating it if you want.

Comment: `Thank you. Yes, I did try that here `axes[0]`.

Comment: @Natasha please tell my what is the type of axes[0].

Comment: Sure, it's `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: @Natasha that's the problem. What's the type of axes[0][0] ?

Comment: It's `<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`

Comment: @natasha try with ```ax=axes[0][0]``` at both plot calls.