# Loop in python to get title tag from a URL

Tags: python, html, loops, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(a))
print (a + soup.title.string)
```

I want to get the titles of the URL with a looping which adds a number every time it gets the URL title.

eg: I get the title for https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234 then https://player.vimeo.com/video/1235 and so on..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over arrays in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_idx, end_idx = 1234, 1245

for idx in range(start_idx, end_idx):
  a = f"https://player.vimeo.com/video/{idx}"
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(a))
  print (f"for url:{a}, title: {soup.title.string}")
```

Set `start_idx` and `end_idx` correctly as you want.

Also you may want to deal with possible HTTPError coming due to forbiddedn access to some urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more `url`, add into `lst`.You got all the title. you can try below script:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lst = ["https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234","https://player.vimeo.com/video/1235"]
title = []
for a in lst:    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(a), 'lxml')
    title.append(soup.title.string)

print(title)
```

Output will be:

```
['Diving catch from Chris Bodenner on Vimeo', 'Hit with box from Chris Bodenner on Vimeo']
```

OR

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lst = ["https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234","https://player.vimeo.com/video/1235"]
title = []
for a in lst:    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(a), 'lxml')
    title.append(soup.title.string)
    print (a + " : " + soup.title.string)
```

Output will be:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234 : Diving catch from Chris Bodenner on Vimeo
https://player.vimeo.com/video/1235 : Hit with box from Chris Bodenner on Vimeo
```