# Using a for loop to loop multiple URLs required for driver.get

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

'Links' contains four URLs which have been appended. How do I create a for loop or arrange my code so entering the URLs for each driver.get can be automated?

My code:

```
links = ['url1','url2','url3','url4']
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\\Downloads\Python\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('url1')
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get('url2')
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.get('url3')
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
driver.get('url4')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over arrays in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3)

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below has a for-loop and is equivalent to your code.

```
links = ['url1','url2','url3','url4']
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\\Downloads\Python\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")

for x in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[x])
    if x < 3:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works but it's worth a try...

```
links = ['url1','url2','url3','url4']
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\\Downloads\Python\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")

def loop_driver():
    counter = 1
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[counter])
        counter += 1
        
loop_driver()
```