# Appending integers to list not recognizing objects as integers

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, append

I am trying to append certain values from, say, list1, as well as a separate object, object1, to another list, list_of_all, using a for loop and .append(). However, whenever I try this, I keep receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Car
```

Here is my code*:

*Please note that `list1` here is the array `comp_cars`, `object1` is `player_car`, and `list_of_all` is `all_times`.

```
def winner():
    all_times = [player_car.time_taken]

    for x in comp_cars:
        all_times.append(comp_cars[x].time_taken)
```

This code *should* make the all_times array be filled with different integers, but instead, I keep getting the same error.

Note: The time_taken value changes each time the code is run, it is randomly generated.

To elaborate, here are what the `comp_cars`' `time_taken` value could be...

```
[40, 32, 60, 78, 99, 23]
```

With the `player_car.time_taken` being...

```
21
```

With those example integers, I would want `all_times` to be...

```
[21, 40, 32, 60, 78, 99, 23]
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? If so, please let me know. Thank you!

Edit: Here is some of the code I have used for creating `comp_cars` & `player_car`.

```
import math
import random
player_car = None
comp_cars = []
comp_players = ["Javontavius", "Jamal", "Jay Z", "Jregory", "Ja'quisha"]
comp_sponsors = ["Alfa Romeo", "Red Bull", "McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"]
class Car:
    def __init__(self, sponsor, name, speed, traction, acceleration, time_taken, skill, points):
        self.sponsor = sponsor
        self.name = name
        self.speed = speed
        self.traction = traction
        self.acceleration = acceleration
        self.time_taken = time_taken
        self.skill = skill
        self.points = points

    def get_time(self):
        temp = 100 / (math.sqrt(self.speed) +
                      math.sqrt(self.traction) / 2 +
                      math.sqrt(self.acceleration) / 2) - (self.skill / 2)

        temp = round(temp)
        return temp

def make_cars():
    temp_name = input("What do you want to name your car? ")
    player_car = Car("You", temp_name, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0)
    player_car.time_taken = player_car.get_time()

    for x in range(0, 4, 1):
        comp_cars.append(Car(comp_sponsors[get_random(0, len(comp_sponsors))], 
                             comp_players[get_random(0, len(comp_players))],  
                             get_random(2, 5),
                             get_random(2, 5),  
                             get_random(2, 5),  
                             None,  
                             get_random(1, 10),  
                                 0)) 
        comp_cars[x].time_taken = comp_cars[x].get_time()
    
def winner():
    all_times = [player_car.time_taken]
    all_owners = [player_car.name]

    for x in comp_cars:
        all_times.append(comp_cars[x].time_taken)
        all_owners.append(comp_cars[x].name)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code is fragmented and incomplete.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've just added the necessary code. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Where is `comp_cars` created? How about `comp_sponsors` and `comp_players`?

Comment: Someone already helped me, their solution works. comp_cars was just an empty array, comp_sponsors and comp_players was just an array of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over arrays in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```py
for x in comp_cars:
    all_times.append(comp_cars[x].time_taken)
```

Here `x` becomes the items in `comp_cars` until the loop is finished. This means you don't need to use `comp_cars[x].time_taken`, but `x.time_taken`. Since `comp_cars` is a list and `x` is not an integer or a slice, you get the TypeError.