# How to check if user input is the same as the first item in each subtuple?

Tags: python

I want to check if user input is the same as any of the first items of the subtuples in a tuple. Then, if it is the same, I want to print the subtuple. I've seen others use `any` but it doesn't work. I'm not really sure how to iterate over all the subtuples because I am given the error message:

```
tupple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
i=0
for i in a[i]:
    if input_city in a [i]:
        print(a[i])
    else:
        i+=1
```

I've also tried:

```
if any(input_city in i for i in a):
    print(a[i])
else:
    print("City does not exist")
```

Basically if I have these tuples:

```
a = (('City A', 1, 2, 3), ('City B', 4, 5, 6))
```

- if user inputs `City A`, then I would print `(City A, 1, 2, 3)`
- if user inputs `City B`, then I would print `(City B, 4, 5, 6)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329668/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-list)

Answer (score 1):

Looping iterates over the items directly, not the indices, so I would call the loop variable `subtuple` instead of `i` and get rid of all the bracketed lookups.

```
for subtuple in a:
    if subtuple[0] == input_city:
        print(subtuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the elements themselves in your for-loop without having to worry about the indexes:

```
>>> city_tuples = (('City A', 1, 2, 3), ('City B', 4, 5, 6))
>>> input_city = input("Please enter a city: ")
Please enter a city: City b
>>> for city_tuple in city_tuples:
...     if city_tuple[0].lower() == input_city.lower():
...         print(city_tuple)
...
('City B', 4, 5, 6)
```

---

> [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)
>
> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters [[4]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id15) converted to lowercase.
>
> The lowercasing algorithm used is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.

Comment: I haven't seen the .lower() used in this before. I was just wondering what's the reason why it was used?

Comment: For example say the user inputs something like `'neW YoRK'` they would still get the tuples which contain `'New York'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for i in a:
    if input_city in i:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

first we talk on your code:

```
i=0
for i in a[i]:
    if input_city in a [i]:
        print(a[i])
    else:
        i+=1
```

line#2: `a[i]`. so you are looping over a tuple `since a[0] is ('City A', 1, 2, 3)` so `i` in first iteration become `City A`. remember this!.

line#3: here you check `if input_city in a[i]`. as we saw the `i` is string `City A`. this means you say `if input_city in a['City A']`. so obviously the error are thrown, since you can't slice tuple by value, but by index.

last line: `i += 1` . no need for this, since python increment this value by default.

Now the working code:

```
for i in a:
    if input_city in i:
        print(i)
```