# How do I iterate through lists with nested lists in Python / why doesn't my code work?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, typeerror

Can someone explain why Python won't let me use i in this manner?

```
unit1 = [["cats allowed", True], ["bedrooms", 0], ["Balcony", False]]

userPref = []
for i in unit1:
   userPref = userPref.append(unit1[i][1])
   print(unit1[i][1])
```

I get this error message:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

If I want to iterate through the second item in each nested list, how would I go about doing that?

(FYI: the for loop in nested in an if statement. I omitted that for simplicity.)

Comment: did you debug it ? `print(i)` in the loop you'll understand, you iterate over values, not indices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329668/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-list)

Comment: you didn't use `append` correctly,
you can see the correct format in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Some options you have to iterate over a list:

1)

```
for item in unit1:
   userPref.append(item[1])
   print(item[1])
```

which `item[1]` is the second parameter of nested list

2)

```
for i in range(len(unit1)):
    userPref.append(unit1[i][1])
    print(unit1[i][1])
```

3. 

or if you need `item` and `index` together:

```
for i,item in enumerate(unit1):
    userPref.append(item[1])
    print(item[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in unit1:
```

When you iterate over a list in this way, `i` becomes each *value* in the list, not the list *index*.

So on the first iteration, `i` is the sub-list `["cats allowed", True]`.

If you want to iterate over the *indexes* of a list, use `range()`:

```
for i in range(len(unit1)):
```

Answer (score 0):

> Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

You can found that differ in [python official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), the iteration will traverse all the value in the sequence rather index of that, which is quite different from other languages.